# How to save comment name email url fields?

Tags: plugins, comments, cache

First of all I must admit that I'm not entirely sure about whether or not this question is allowed here (as this is not code debugging question), but still asking in hope some wp users can show me some light on this matter.

In wordpress if a website is using the default wordpress comment form the fileds that shows up besides the text area to post the comment are - name, email & website url. Now when someone post the comment for the first time they put all those details there and next time when he revisit the site, those same files should be auto populated with the previous details. (in theory)

But this is not happening on my site, I'm not getting the point whether this feature is not present in wordpress or should I have to install some plugin for that (if yes, then what plugin) or have to write some custom code using wordpress object caching function or this is happening due to caching plugin (using WP Rockets).

So if you guys can give me some idea like on which path should I walk to achieve this, it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely side effect of your caching plugin.

WP stores this information in user's cookies and tries to read them to fill in the form. However since it happens on server side it needs to output info into a page's source. So if page is being served from cache it just doesn't work.

As far as I remember full page cache plugins tend to have option to not serve cached pages to known commenters. However that obviously reduces efficiency of caching and might not be a practical option, depending on how *many* visitors are such.

Comment: Well my site is a pretty active site and a lot of people visit it, post comment on it everyday. WP Rocket has an option to not cache a page when certain cookie is enabled. So can you tell me the name of the cookie that wordpress uses so that I can add it in the reject list?

Comment: Not on top of my head. :) Configuring plugin you use sounds like a question best aimed at its support.

Comment: Not to worry. The info you gave me earlier helped me to figure it out and fixed it. Thanks again.